# Ordenar la columna de pandas alfanuméricas en orden ascendente

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo una dataframe con columnas alfanuméricas. Me gustaría clasificarlos en un orden ascendente:

```
    Answer-1    Answer0     Answer1     Answer10    Answer100   Answer101   Answer102   Answer103   Answer104   Answer105   ...     Answer98    Answer99    Answers     QID     QType   Questions   Section     Theme   Topics  URL
2649    10+     NaN     1   10  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     ...     NaN     NaN     ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']    1048    Likert Scale    How many times do you usually travel via airplane in a year     What changes would you like to see on your flight in the future? If any.    Airline XYZ     ['time', 'usual', 'travel', 'airplan', 'year']  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1qQ28JBZE-8Mk-4wfCNfejz-_2AGKLWPUIBuzhsFE-kg/edit?usp=sharing
4155    5 or more   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     ...     NaN     NaN     ['012345']  2906    Likert Scale    How many flights were cancelled/affected by the global lockdown?    Media consumption   Airline XYZ     ['flight', 'cancel', 'affect', 'global', 'lockdown']    https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1yPWGOPVpk2HEj7M-2XbJDdm3EvmRozos-upH7wI9VvY/edit?usp=sharing
...
```

Ya he intentado algo, que resultó en lo que se puede ver arriba, pero parece que hay un problema con las docenas:

```
df_merged[df_merged['QType'] == 'Likert Scale'].sort_values(by='Answer0', ascending=True)
```

Comment: ¿Quieres clasificar por nombre de columna entonces?

Comment: Podrias renombrar las columnas Answer001, Answer002, ..., Answer010, ...

Comment: No se entiende, necesita clarificación. ¿Quieres ordenar los nombres de las columnas o quieres ordenar los contenidos de una columna particular? Si es lo segundo, ¿por qué no funciona el código de ejemplo que pones? ¿qué "problema con las docenas" es ese? ¿puedes poner un ejemplo de lo que te sale y de lo que querrías que saliera?

Comment: @abulafia Si ordenar los nombres de las columnas sobre los numeros, obtener una cosa como Answer1, Answer2, Answer3..., Answer99, Answer100, Answer101... en lugar de Answer1,Answer10,Answer100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que, al ser los nombres de las columnas cadenas, la ordenación es alfanumérica, y "100" va antes de "2" alfanuméricamente, porque comienza por "1" que va antes de "2".

La solución es usar una función que convierta cada cadena a otro objeto para el cual la ordenación funcione correctamente.

Por ejemplo, considera la siguiente función:

```
import re

def convertir(nombre):
  m = re.match(r"Answer(-?\d+)", nombre)
  if m:
    return ("Answer", int(m.group(1)))
  return (nombre, 0)
```

Esta función recibe un nombre como "Answer2", o "Answer-1", o "Foobar" y realiza lo siguiente:

1. Comprueba si la cadena tiene la forma "Answer" seguida de un signo - opcional y de uno o varios dígitos.
2. Si es así, retorna la tupla formada por la cadena "Answer" y el número en cuestión *una vez convertido en `int`*
3. Si no es así, retorna una tupla formada por el nombre (por ejemplo "Foobar") y el entero 0.

Las tuplas que resultan de esta función sí se ordenarían como querías, porque se compararía primero el primer elemento de la tupla, y en caso de que sean iguales (como en todas las "Answer") se compararía entonces el segundo elemento que al ser de tipo `int` proporciona la ordenación correcta. Por ejemplo `("Answer", 2)` va antes de `("Answer", 100)`.

Puedes pasarle esa función como argumento `key` a la función `sorted()`, para ordenar una lista de nombres así:

```
nombres = ['Answer-1', 'Answer0', 'Answer1', 'Answer10', 'Answer100',
     'Answer101', 'Answer102', 'Answer103', 'Answer104', 'Answer105',
     'Answer98', 'Answer99', 'Answers', 'QID', 'QType', 'Questions',
     'Section', 'Theme', 'Topics', 'URL']

print(sorted(nombres, key=convertir)
```

y obtienes

```
['Answer-1', 'Answer0', 'Answer1', 'Answer10', 'Answer98', 'Answer99',
 'Answer100', 'Answer101', 'Answer102', 'Answer103', 'Answer104', 'Answer105',
 'Answers', 'QID', 'QType', 'Questions', 'Section', 'Theme', 'Topics', 'URL']
```

Observa que la función `convertir` se usa sólo para decidir cómo ordenar los elementos de la lista, pero no se modifican los valores de esos elementos.

### Aplicación a tu caso:

Aunque no puedo probarlo por no tener tu dataframe, creo que lo siguiente debería funcionar:

```
df = df[list(sorted(df.columns, key=convertir))]
```

ya que `df.columns` dará la lista de nombres de columnas, que será ordenado con `sorted()` y la función `key` antes vista para dar otra lista ya en el orden deseado, y esa lista se usa para seleccionar columnas en `df`, que quedarán por tanto reordenadas, y el resultado se guarda de nuevo en `df`.

### Bonus

Con una ligera modificación, la función `convertir` puede hacerse más general y por tanto más útil:

```
def convertir(nombre):
  m = re.match(r"(.*?)(-?\d+)", nombre)
  if m:
    return (m.group(1), int(m.group(2)))
  return (nombre, 0)
```

En este caso ya no se busca explícitamente la cadena "Answer", sino que la expresión regular separa la parte alfabética de la parte numérica, sea cual sea la parte alfabética, y se retorna una tupla con la parte alfabética tal cual y la numérica convertida a `int`. De este modo funcionará si en la lista hay más nombres del estilo "Foo1", "Foo2", etc.

Ejemplo:

```
ej = ["Foo", "Foo100", "Foo2", "Bar", "Answer50", "Answer12", "Zeppo", "Groucho"]

print(sorted(ej, key=convertir))
```

---

```
['Answer12', 'Answer50', 'Bar', 'Foo', 'Foo2', 'Foo100', 'Groucho', 'Zeppo']
```